# Expressing parametric equations of a spiral in terms of X coordinate

Tags: trigonometry, parametric, parametrization

I'd like to draw the spiral as a bitmap graphics.

Given a simplified parametric form of an Archimedean spiral for *x* and *y* as functions of *t*:

```
x(t) = t * sin(t)
y(t) = t * cos(t)
```

How can I derive **y** as function of **x** (`y(x)`)? Is that possible and what would be the steps?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Well, $x^2+y^2=t^2$, and $x/y=\tan(t)$, so perhaps you could do $x^2+y^2=\left(\text{Tan}^{-1}(x/y)\right)^2$.

Although there would probably be some issues with the domain this works on, and how to convert this into the form $y=f(x)$. But hopefully this is a start to get it into cartesian form.